# Knockout: avoid circular updates in a binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have a custom binding that interfaces with [Scribe](https://github.com/guardian/scribe), a contenteditable WYSIWYG editor. It updates the associated observable when the editor content changes, and updates the editor when the associated observable does:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.editor = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var $element    = $(element),
        content     = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
        scribe;

    // create a new editor instance
    scribe = new Scribe(element);

    // store it for later access in our 'update' handler
    $element.data('scribe', scribe);

    // set the initial editor content
    scribe.setContent(content);

    // update the observable whenever the editor changes
    scribe.on('content-changed', function() {
      var observable  = valueAccessor(),
          content     = scribe.getHTML();

      observable(content);
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var $element    = $(element),
        content     = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

    // update the editor content when the observable changes
    $element.data('scribe').setContent(content);
  }
};
```

The problem is this:

1. user types into the editor
2. the editor component sends a "changed" event
3. the event handler updates the observable
4. the bindings' "update" handler is triggered, writing the change right back to the editor

Usually that would not be a big deal, just unnecessary. But in my case, `editor.setContent` has the side effect of resetting the cursor position to the beginning of the input - [everything you enter is reversed](http://gfycat.com/ShockingRequiredCormorant).

I need the editor to be updated, if - and only if - the observable is changed somewhere else in the application. What I am looking for is a way to avoid updating the editor with changes that originated in the editor itself in the first place.

How can I best avoid these circular updates?

**Update:**
I have found an obvious way of sidestepping my immediate problem - in the update handler, simply compare the observable content to the current editor content before making the update:

```
  if ($element.data('scribe').getHTML() !== content) {
    $element.data('scribe').setContent(content);
  }
```

I would still be interested in a general answer, if just for the sake of avoiding unnecessary update calls.

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the issue but this might help: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html or possibly look to use valuHasMutated, sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/98e52/118/

Comment: Thanks @Tanner! I've rewritten the question - hopefully the issue becomes more clear now.

Comment: Other than checking to see if there is really a change, another thought would be to move your `update` functionality into a computed in `init` and check a shared flag that you set before updating the observable and clear afterwards. Computed would look like: `ko.computed(function() { //your update stuff }, null, { disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element });`

Comment: Thanks @RPNiemeyer! I'll give that a shot. Also - nice, I was not aware of `disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [RPNiemeyers recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685842/knockout-avoid-circular-updates-in-a-binding#comment40149514_25685842), I moved the observable -> component updating functionality from the bindings' `update` handler into the `init` handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.editor = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var $element                = $(element),
        content                 = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
        ignoreObservableChanges = false,
        scribe;

    scribe = new Scribe(element);

    $element.data('scribe', scribe);

    scribe.setContent(content);

    scribe.on('content-changed', function() {
      var observable  = valueAccessor(),
          content     = scribe.getHTML();

      ignoreObservableChanges = true;
      observable(content);
      ignoreObservableChanges = false;
    });

    valueAccessor().subscribe(function(newValue) {
      if (ignoreObservableChanges) {
        return;
      }

      scribe.setContent(newValue);
    });
  }
};
```

Both the component -> observable updater and the observable -> component updater now share the `ignoreObservableChanges` flag in their scope, so the former can instruct the latter when to skip an update.