# How to update ckeditor data when binding it as knockout observable?

Tags: knockout.js, ckeditor

I am trying to work with ckeditor as a knockout.js observable and I am running into some trubles.
For a start here is my code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.CKEDITOR = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         var ckEditorValue = valueAccessor();
         var id = $(element).attr('id');
         var options = allBindings().EditorOptions;
         var instance = CKEDITOR.replace(id, {
             on: {
                 change: function () {
                     // This moves the caret to the start of the editor on each key pressed
                     ckEditorValue(instance.getData());
                 }
             }
         });
         // instance.setData(ckEditorValue());
     },
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
         var id = $(element).attr('id');
         var ckEditorValue = valueAccessor();
         CKEDITOR.instances[id].setData(ckEditorValue());
     }
};
```

The problem I'm facing with this code is that on each key I press and the `change` event is firing the caret moves to the tope start position of the editor.
I tried calling the `blur` event instead of the `change` event but it doesn't fire when I click the save button, it fires only when I click on a blank place or moving to a nother control.

How can I keep my observable updated then ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had [a similar issue with a different editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685842/knockout-avoid-circular-updates-in-a-binding), and solved it by removing the `update` handler and replacing it with a manual subscription. This way, you can introduce some shared state that says 'skip this update, that was me':

```
ko.bindingHandlers.CKEDITOR = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var ckEditorValue = valueAccessor();
    var id = $(element).attr('id');
    var options = allBindings().EditorOptions;
    var ignoreChanges = false;

    var instance = CKEDITOR.replace(id, {
      on: {
        change: function() {
          ignoreChanges = true;
          ckEditorValue(instance.getData());
          ignoreChanges = false;
        }
      }
    });

    ckEditorValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
      if (!ignoreChanges) {
        instance.setData(newValue);
      }
    });

  }
};
```

Comment: Great solution. 10X :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extended KO Binding for [CKEditor v4.6.2 *(12 Jan 2017)*](http://ckeditor.com).
I wanted to use the expected behavior of 'update'
This will ensure the observable value is update on the 'blur' event.

This has taken a while to fine tune, so I hope this is useful to someone.

```
/**
*   Custom KO binding for jQuery CKEditor plugin v4.2.6
*   {@link http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery Original Reference}
*   Usage: <div data-bind="ckeditor: { [ CKEditor init options should be placed here.] }, value: $data.value"></div>
*/
ko.bindingHandlers.ckeditor = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = valueAccessor();
        var binding = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor()).value;

        options = ko.utils.extend(ko.bindingHandlers.ckeditor.options, options);

        // Set an ID if the element doesn't already have one assigned
        var elemId = $(element).attr('id');
        if(typeof elemId === "undefined") {
            elemId = 'ck_' + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
            $(element).attr('id', elemId);
        }

        var ckeditorId = $(element).attr("id");

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            var ckInst = eval( "CKEDITOR.instances." + ckeditorId );
            if ( ckInst ) ckInst.destroy();
        });

        $(element).ckeditor( options );

        // wire up the source button click event to copy the value
        CKEDITOR.instances[ckeditorId].on('afterCommandExec', handleAfterCommandExec);
        function handleAfterCommandExec(event) {
            var commandName = event.data.name;
            // For 'source' commmand
            if (commandName == 'source')
                //console.log("source button pressed!");
                binding( $(element).val() );
        }

        // wire up the blur event to ensure our observable is properly updated
        CKEDITOR.instances[ckeditorId].focusManager.blur = function () {
            var ckInst = eval( "CKEDITOR.instances." + ckeditorId );
            //console.log('blur!');
            //console.log( $(element).val() );
            binding( $(element).val() );
        };

    },
    update:  function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(allBindingsAccessor.get('value'));

        // only update the code when there are differences
        if ( value !== $(element).val() ) {
            $(element).val(value);
        }
    },
    options: {
        toolbar: [
            { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format' ] },
            { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ], items: [ 'Source' ] },
            { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'undo' ], items: [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
            { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ], items: [ 'Scayt' ] },
            { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },
            { name: 'others', items: [ '-' ] },
            { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] },
            '/',
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ], items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
            { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ] },
            { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
            { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: I went with this and worked great. A small improvement: on blur your solution won't hide the toolbar. In my case it was covering another field just above. To have it hide use this: `var oldBlur=CKEDITOR.instances[ckeditorId].focusManager.blur;CKEDITOR.instances[ckeditorId].focusManager.blur=function(){var ckInst=eval("CKEDITOR.instances."+ckeditorId);binding($(element).html());oldBlur.call(CKEDITOR.instances[ckeditorId].focusManager);};`

Answer (score 0):

I know that i am a bit late to answer this but i have been struggling with this for a while, my problem was that i needed the user to EITHER type in the box OR add a template via a button, all the solutions that i found was addressing EITHER of the problems but not both.

The fiddle below addresses both typing in the box (keeping the cursor at the right position and not resetting to position 0) and also clicking a button to trigger a KO function to update the data in the editor.

Here is the custom binding that achieves this

```
    var TOOLBAR_CONFIG = [{
    name: 'document',
    items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'DocProps', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']
  }, {
    name: 'clipboard',
    items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']
  }, {
    name: 'editing',
    items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt']
  }, {
    name: 'forms',
    items: ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
      'HiddenField'
    ]
  },
  '/', {
    name: 'basicstyles',
    items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']
  }, {
    name: 'paragraph',
    items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv',
      '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl'
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'links',
    items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']
  }, {
    name: 'insert',
    items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']
  },
  '/', {
    name: 'styles',
    items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']
  }, {
    name: 'colors',
    items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor']
  }, {
    name: 'tools',
    items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-', 'About']
  }
];

ko.bindingHandlers.ckeditor = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  var ignoreChanges = false;
    var options = ko.utils.extend({
      toolbar: TOOLBAR_CONFIG,
      removePlugins: 'elementspath'
    }, allBindings.get('ckeditorOptions') || {});
    var modelValue = valueAccessor();

    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(element, options);

    editor.on('change', function() {
    ignoreChanges = true;
      modelValue(editor.getData());
      ignoreChanges = false;
    });

modelValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
var editor = new CKEDITOR.dom.element(element).getEditor();
if (!(ignoreChanges))
       editor.setData(newValue);
    });

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      if (editor) {
        CKEDITOR.remove(editor);
      };
    });
  },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var editor = new CKEDITOR.dom.element(element).getEditor();
        console.log(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
        editor.setData(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()), null, true);
    }
};
```

Working example

http://jsfiddle.net/gr71bzwx/10/